# Having problems with python permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am having some problem with permutations! I am a really big noob when it comes to python so any help would be appreciated!

Lets say I have a list that ranges from 1-6 in a text file, so e.g
it looks like (1,2,3,4,5,6) I want to open said .txt file and calculate all possible combinations of N of those 6 numbers up to N=4.

when i use itertools permutations

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 
2), (2, 3), 
(2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 
5), (3, 6), 
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 
2), (5, 3), 
 (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6,5), 
(6, 6)]
```

it outputs the numbers like this, which i don't really want, since i can only get all combinations of one number of numbers at a time - But I want all possible combinations of N numbers with N ranging from 1 to 4, including repeats such as:

```
(1,1), (1,1,1) (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1)
```

So I want it to have repeats, have combinations with a different number of members, however not go past 4 combinations of the number. I am really struggling with this concept! If anything doesn't make sense don't hesitate to ask me :)

Comment: Could you be more specific about the output you expect?

Comment: Do you want to return all possible combinations, including the ones with repeats; or do you *only* wnat the ones with repeats?

Comment: @flob I want all possible combinations, including the ones with repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

LIMIT = 4
l1 = [1,2,3]

results = []

for i in range(1, LIMIT+1):
    results.extend(product(l1, repeat=i))

print(results)
```

will yield:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), 
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), 
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), 
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), 
(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), 
(1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), 
(1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), 
(2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), 
(2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), 
(2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), 
(3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), 
(3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), 
(3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3), 
(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3), 
(1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3), 
(1, 1, 3, 1), (1, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 3, 3), 
(1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 3), 
(1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 3), 
(1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3, 3), 
(1, 3, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2), (1, 3, 1, 3), 
(1, 3, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2, 3), 
(1, 3, 3, 1), (1, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3, 3), 
(2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1, 3), 
(2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2, 3), 
(2, 1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3), 
(2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1, 3), 
(2, 2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 3), 
(2, 2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 3, 2), (2, 2, 3, 3),
(2, 3, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1, 3), 
(2, 3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2, 3), 
(2, 3, 3, 1), (2, 3, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3, 3), 
(3, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 1, 3), 
(3, 1, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 1, 2, 3), 
(3, 1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 3, 3), 
(3, 2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1, 3), 
(3, 2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 2, 3), 
(3, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 3, 3), 
(3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 3, 1, 2), (3, 3, 1, 3), 
(3, 3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 2, 3), 
(3, 3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: This is what im looking for @andreihondrari Thank you so much !

Comment: @Rory Daulton: I have done what you have recommended, thank you !

Comment: Quick question? How would you also do this without repeats? I would just like to grasp both ways !

Comment: @matthewkemp repeats you mean like without (1,1) (1,1,1)...? For that you would need [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) used like `results.extend(permutations(l1, i))`

Comment: @matthewkemp You can get a full sense of these under `Combinatoric iterators` on the [itertools page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: No thats not what i mean, i mean repeats such as (1,1,1,2) and (1,2,1,1) so they are the same set of numbers however just different ordered. Is there a way to eliminate this? Hope this is clear!

Comment: Ok I shall have a look there aswell ! Thank you :)

Comment: @matthewkemp then `combinations_with_replacement` is your answer.